# How to check if an item has a comma and after that only two digits

Tags: javascript

**I have the following part of code:**

```
this.product.unitprice
  .toLocaleString()
  .substring(this.product.unitprice.toString().length-3)
  .indexOf(',')==-1)
```

I want to check if I have ,00 -> Only this is valid, anything else is not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Be careful using toLocaleString as some currencies have the comma and the period opposite way round

Comment: i know that ... but in my case it will be comma

Comment: `if( this.product.unitprice.match(/,\d{2}/) )`

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex 
`^\,[0-9]{2}$`
This represents comma followed by only two digits.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need :

```js
price = '1,00,250,00';

// just for the ,00 comparision
if(price.substr(price.length - 3) == ',00'){
  console.log("Good to go");
} else {
  console.log("Noooooooo");
}

// will check for ,xx (x=any digit)
var patt = new RegExp(",[0-9]{2}$");
if(patt.test(price)){
  console.log("Good to go");
} else {
  console.log("Noooooooo");
}
```

Comment: its not good because i need to check if it will be ,xx -> this can be any two digit number

Comment: @None , please check the second version , it will work for all digits

Answer (score 0):

```
price="1,000,000"
if(price.replace(/,[0-9][0-9]/,"")!=price){
   console.log(true+"good")
}
else{
   console.log(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use a regex :

```
var regex = /^\d*\.\d{2}$/;
var num = '23894445.09';
alert(regex.test(num));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<script>
myFunction("200,00");
myFunction("1234,000");

function myFunction(str) {   
    var commaPosition = str.indexOf(",") +1;
    var strLength = str.length;
    
    if(commaPosition != 0 && (strLength - commaPosition) == 2)
    {
     alert("Has two characters after comma!");
    }
    else{
     alert("No two characters after comma!");
    }
}
</script>
```